# JSON object as key in key-value pair

Tags: javascript, json, object, key

I see this isn't possible (in JavaScript), would this be due to serialization for persistance?

ActionScript3 does allow object *instances* as keys [flash.utils.Dictionary](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html)

Then again, string Id's would serve the same uniqueness purpose of the instance, right?

Comment: The language simply doesn't allow it. Object property names are strings, and only strings.

Comment: Just out of interest: What can be the use case for this? And how would one access it?

Comment: Since JSON can only be contained in *strings* in JS, you can use JSON as key. E.g. `var obj = {'{"foo": 42}': "bar"};`. If you mean a JS object, no, that's not possible.

Comment: You can use objects as keys, but they're converted into strings. *But* for your classes you can define the `toString` method on the prototype, so they can return an unique value.

Comment: @sanusart see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316396/json-object-as-key-in-key-value-pair/20316629#comment43973016_20316629 for a use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what [ES6 `Map` is for](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/10/09/ecmascript-6-collections-part-2-maps/), it allows to use an object as key:

```
var map = new Map();
var obj1 = {};
var obj2 = {}; // identical, but not the same

map.set(obj1, 'value');

map.get(obj1); // 'value'
map.get(obj2); // undefined
```

Demo (Firefox and IE 11): http://jsbin.com/ehIgEha/1/edit?js,console, browser support: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#Map

Comment: I'm trying hard, and drawing a blank. What would be a use case for this?

Comment: @Willem: Imagine you have a mapping `user -> posts`. Sure you could just use the user ID as key (`user_id -> posts`) and have another mapping `user_id -> user`, but being able to use any data type as key is more convenient and flexible. Additionally, the implicit conversion of values used as property names to strings can be confusing and the source of bugs. A more practical example might be the a mapping of `DOMElement -> data`.

Comment: @FelixKling For a mapping `DOMElement -> data` WeakMap should be used.

Comment: @Pavlo: Good point. I was just giving generals ideas where proper maps could be useful.

Comment: Thank you. That's actually pretty smart, and will be very useful.. Almost like people have thought this through. ;)

Comment: @Pavlo Thank you, this is exactly what I asked for.
@WillemLabu This is very useful for creating key->value pairs for objects that don't necessarily have a unique id (Maps remove the need to implement unique-id generation in these cases). The `DOMElement->data` example in Pavlo's link (http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/10/09/ecmascript-6-collections-part-2-maps/) is a good example of a use case for this.